# Problems with R while loop

Tags: r, while-loop

I have a dataset like this:

```
        X         Y                A            B           C
1       1        2010              1            1          44
2       1        2010              1            2          17
3       1        2010              1            3           0
4       1        2010              1            4           0
5       1        2010              1            5           0
6       1        2010              1            6           0
...
```

My aim is to take the values in C that correspond to `X==1&Y==2006&A==seq(1,19)&B==19.`
I thought I should use a While loop making something like this:

```
for (i in 1:19){
  while (X==1){
    while (Y==2006){
      while (B==19){
        x[i]<-A[i]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nonetheless, the code above doesn't work and there are always warnings() like "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including your data. I assume that that neither x nor A are vectors but matrices/data.frames...

Comment: Is your question to return those values in column C where the X, Y, A and B match your conditions? If so, you do not need a loop in R and you can use the inherent vectorisation of many functions. If your dataset is `data` it could look like this: `data[data$X == 1 & data$Y == 2006 & data$A %in% 1:19 & data$B == 19, "C"]`. This is basic sub-setting in R. But I may misunderstand what you are after.

Comment: Do you need `subset(df, X==1 & Y==2006 & A %in% 1:19 & B==19)` ?

Comment: One of ther great strengths of R is that it works on *columns* not *values*.  That means that, generally, speaking, if you're considering using a for loop, then there is generally a better (= quicker, shorter) solution.+1 to @RonakShah's suggestion.

Comment: yeah @RonakShah u got it! Thank u very much